Salesforce LWC dynamic data table column
I have created a custom LWC component that will display a list of records on an experience cloud page.  It essentially is a custom list view component that will display the title of the list view in the logged-in user's language.  The client wants this dynamic so that the object, list of columns and fields, and title can be determined at design time.
A couple of questions:

When the custom LWC component is placed on the Experience Cloud page, the data table's columns are always displayed in English even though the user's language is set to Spanish.  Is that normal behavior of LWC?
For the Title, I ended up using custom labels to do the translation and it works great.  However, I am not sure how I will be able to accomplish that for the table columns.  The design time value for a table column looks like this:  [{label:'Application Status',fieldName:'Status',sortable:true}]  So, if the user's language is spanish, then I want the Status column to say "estado".

HTML Code:
<template>  
    <lightning-card title = "{Title}">  
        <template if:true = {listRecs}>                  
            <div style="height: 300px;">  
                <lightning-datatable key-field="Id" 
                                        data={listRecs}  
                                        columns={columns}  
                                        hide-checkbox-column="true"  
                                        show-row-number-column="true"
                                        default-sort-direction={defaultSortDirection}
                                        sorted-direction={sortDirection}
                                        sorted-by={sortedBy}
                                        onsort={onHandleSort}
                                        onrowaction={handleRowAction}>  
                </lightning-datatable>  
            </div>                   
        </template>  
    </lightning-card>  
</template>

XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>62.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default, lightning__RecordPage">
            <property name="RelatedObject" type="String"/>
            <property name="Fields" type="String"/>
            <property name="TableColumns" type="String"/>
            <property name="Title" type="String"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>

JS CODE
import { api, LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';  
import fetchRecs from '@salesforce/apex/sk_CustomListViewController.fetchRecs';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import basePath from '@salesforce/community/basePath'

import customtitle from "@salesforce/label/c.custom_title";

export default class GfcCustomListView extends LightningElement {
    @track listRecs;  
    @track initialListRecs;
    @track error;  
    @track columns;  
    @api RelatedObject;
    @api Fields;
    @api RelatedField;
    @api TableColumns;
    @api Title;
    sortedBy;
    defaultSortDirection = 'asc';
    sortDirection = 'asc';

    connectedCallback() {
        if(this.TableColumns !== undefined) {
            this.columns = JSON.parse( this.TableColumns.replace( /([a-zA-Z0-9]+?):/g, '"$1":' ).replace( /'/g, '"' ));
        }
    }

    get vals() {  
        return this.RelatedObject + '-' + this.Fields + '-' +   
            this.RelatedField + '-' + this.AccountId;  
    }

    @wire(fetchRecs, { listValues: '$vals' })  
    wiredRecs( { error, data } ) {
        if ( data ) {
            this.initialListRecs = data;
            this.Title = customtitle; //title replaced by language via custom label
            let nameUrl;
            this.listRecs = data.map(row => { 
                nameUrl = basePath +'/' + this.RelatedObject.toLowerCase() + '/'+ row.Id;
                return {...row , nameUrl} 
            })
        } else if ( error ) {
            this.listRecs = null;
            this.initialListRecs = null;
            this.error = error
        }
    }
}




Yes, you have to write the LWC to handle localization. Take a look here for some details. 2. Use of labels is appropriate for generic text. For column titles consider accessing the schema to get the label or plural label for the relevant object or the given field as needed. This might help.

